# Return date range by group

Tags: r, date, aggregate

I want to group by color and calculate the date range for that color. I have tried `group_by()`, `summarize()` and `aggregate()`.

```
#Data:
df1 <- as.Date(c('Jul 1', 'Jun 26', 'July 5', 'July 15'), format = '%B %d')
df2 <- c("red", "blue", "red", "blue")

df1 <- data.frame(df1,df2)
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
#  Group.1   x
[1]   4     red
[2]   19    blue
```

I have been trying this:

```
df <- aggregate(df1[,1], list(df1[,2]), as.numeric(max(df1[,1]) - min(df1[,1]), units="days"))
```

I have tested `as.numeric(max(df1[,1]) - min(df1[,1]), units="days")` and it returns the value that I'm looking for, I just can't figure out how to return that value for each color.

My Error Message is below, but I think realistically, I'm just going about this the wrong way.

```
 Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
      'as.numeric(max(df1$date) - min(df1$date), units = "days")' is not a function, character or symbol
```

after reading through `aggregate()` document I tried to use the `formula =` for the last argument and returned this error:

`Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Not that your column names are `df1` and `df2` `aggregate(df1~ df2, df1, diff)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
 df1 %>% 
   group_by(df2) %>% 
   summarise(Range=max(df1) - min(df1))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  df2   Range  
  <fct> <drtn> 
1 blue  19 days
2 red    4 days
```

Comment: Beauty, Thanks! I tried something similar but was missing the `Range=` form of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(df1~ df2, df1, function(x) diff(range(x)))
```

---

Note that the column names of 'df1' are 'df1' and 'df2' and it creates some confusion.  Instead, it may be better to create the data ass

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = df1, Group = df2)
```

and then with the formula method,

```
aggregate(x~ Group, df1, diff)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require(dplyr)

df001 <- as.Date(c('Jul 1', 'Jun 26', 'July 5', 'July 15'), format = '%B %d')
df002 <- c("red", "blue", "red", "blue")

df003 <- data.frame(df001,df002)


df003 %>%  rename(dates = df001, colors = df002) %>% 
  group_by(colors) %>% 
  summarise(min_date = min(dates), max_date = max(dates)) %>%  
  mutate(range = max_date - min_date) %>%  
  select(colors, range)


# 
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# colors range 
# <fct>  <time>
#   1 blue   19    
#   2 red    4
```